# Sybase select distinct on one column, do not care about others

Tags: sql, distinct, aggregate-functions, sybase

I have seen many similar questions but none that meet my needs exactly, and I cannot seem to deduce a solution on my own from inspecting the other questions.

I have the following (mock) table below.  My actual table has many more columns.

```
TableA:

ID  | color | feel   | size   | alive | age
------------------------------------------
1   | blue  | soft   | large  | true  | 36
2   | red   | soft   | large  | true  | 36
2   | blue  | hard   | small  | false | 37
2   | blue  | soft   | large  | true  | 36
2   | blue  | soft   | small  | false | 39
15  | blue  | soft   | medium | true  | 04
15  | blue  | soft   | large  | true  | 04
15  | green | soft   | large  | true  | 15
40  | pink  | sticky | large  | true  | 83
51  | brown | rough  | tiny   | false | 01
51  | gray  | soft   | tiny   | true  | 59
34  | blue  | soft   | large  | true  | 02
```

I want the result to look like:

```
Result of query on TableA:

ID  | color | feel   | size   | alive | age
-------------------------------------------
1   | blue  | soft   | large  | true  | 36
2   | red   | soft   | large  | true  | 36
15  | blue  | soft   | medium | true  | 04
40  | pink  | sticky | large  | true  | 83
51  | brown | rough  | tiny   | false | 01
34  | blue  | soft   | large  | true  | 02
```

I want one row for every unique ID column, but I do not want to check the other columns.  I need the other columns returned in my result set, but I do not want to filter on them.  I just need one row for every unique ID - I do not care which row.

In my example, I selected the first row of every unique ID.

I have tried variations of

```
select * 
from TableA 
group by ID having ID = max(ID)
```

Most examples I have seen with group by and max and/or min functions involve only 2 columns.  I have many more columns, however.

I have also seen examples using CTE, but I am not using SQL Server (I am using Sybase).

How can I achieve the result set described?

**EDIT**

We are using Sybase version 15.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this.  If you have a more recent version of Sybase, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Our department is UPGRADING to 15.1... :(  I don't see row_number in these docs: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01087.1510/pdf/iqnew.pdf

Comment: does sybase support this?  this looks like MS SQL SERVER

Comment: To clarify, this does NOT work on the version of Sybase we are using (15.1).

Comment: @TMcKeown . . . The use of "Sybase" as a database tag is almost useless because there are so many versions that people regularly use.  Here is one that does support this functionality:  http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/iqrefbb262.htm.

Comment: @SoylentGreen . . . Does your version of Sybase support `rowid`?

Comment: If you have Sybase IQ just use rank() instead of row_number().

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with MIN has some drawbacks. It doesn't return you a specific row but MIN values from the group of rows. You can get as result rows which are not in database. Is it OK for you ?

Row_number is supported in sybase 15.2

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/iqrefbb262.htm

It's sad if it is not supported in 15.1. You can use then identity column and temporary table to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have come up with is below.

It "feels" like a poor solution - I am still open to new answers:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    min(color),
    min(feel),
    min(size),
    min(alive),
    min(age)
FROM TableA
group by ID
```

I do not like how verbose I am with the application of the `min` function to every column, but this returns the desired result set.

Comment: But this will put values from different rows on the same row. Doesn't seem to make much sense. If you *absolutely* do not care about the contents of those columns but do need to return something, you could just as well return NULLs.